# How to write Splunk query to get first and last request time for each sources along with each source counts in a table output

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the following Splunk table data from a Splunk query output.

```
Source        RequestTime
SourceX     10/07/2020 04:03 AM  
SourceX     10/07/2020 07:15 AM 
SourceX     10/07/2020 11:19 AM
SourceY     10/07/2020 09:13 AM
SourceY     10/07/2020 11:09 AM
SourceY     10/07/2020 03:29 PM 
SourceY     10/07/2020 07:08 PM 
SourceZ     10/07/2020 09:43 AM 
SourceZ     10/07/2020 01:44 PM
SourceZ     10/07/2020 07:08 PM
SourceZ     10/07/2020 08:09 PM
```

Please help me to get the output as below table format.

```
Source    SourceCount     StartTime              EndTime
SourceX      3         10/07/2020 04:03 AM    10/07/2020 11:19 AM 
SourceY      4         10/07/2020 09:13 AM    10/07/2020 07:08 PM 
SourceZ      4         10/07/2020 09:43 AM    10/07/2020 08:09 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

The `stats` command can do that.

```
... | stats count as SourceCount, min(RequestTime) as StartTime, max(RequestTime) as EndTime by Source
```

Comment: `min()` and `max()` won't work with text.  The RequestTime field will have to be converted to epoch form to do min/max.  I'm assuming the field *is* text, but we don't know since the query that produced the example table was not shared.